# Is it true that every positive integer is the sum of 18 fourth powers of integers?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is it true that every positive integer is the sum of $18$ fourth powers of integers?

Does this means every positive integer $n = x_1^4+x_2^4+\cdots+x_n^4$ for some positive integer $n=18$? 
Could you show me some example, I don't think I am understanding the question..( ex:
Explanation says $78$ can be written as a sum of $18$ fourth powers of integers, how? Can $1$ or $5$ be written as sum of $18$ fourth powers of integers?)

Thanks!

Comment: using underscores makes subscripts more readable; e.g. `x_1^4` gives $x_1^4$.

Comment: 0 is a fourth power.

Comment: 1 can be written as $1^4$, and 5 can be written as $1^4+1^4+1^4+1^4+1^4$ The trick is then for numbers larger than 18, where is basic trick does not work. Think of this trick: given a number n, look at the largest power $x_1^4$ that is smaller than n, then look at the difference n-$x^4$, and find the largest integer $x_2$ with $x_2^4$< n-$x^4$, and so on.

Comment: @gary: Your "greedy" algorithm is not the best! For instance, it decomposes $160$ into $20$ fourth powers $(81+4 \times 16+15 \times 1)$, but we know that $19$ fourth powers are always enough $(160=10 \times 16)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) for $k=4$. The answer to your question is *no* because 79 requires 19 fourth-powers, as reported in the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 7):

Note that some of the integers may be 0.  So $1 = 1^4 + 0^4 + \ldots + 0^4$.  $78 = 4 \times 2^4 + 14 \times 1^4$.  But what about 79?

Answer (score 6):

This is called [Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) and is a nontrivial problem.  It is actually known that there are numbers which *cannot* be written as the sum of $18$ fourth powers.  Waring's problem states that every number, however, can be written as the sum of $19$ fourth powers.

As for your example, $1$ is the sum of $18$ fourth powers since

$$
1 = 1^4 + \underbrace{0^4 + \dots 0^4}_{17~\text{times}}.
$$

Comment: Don't you mean *fourth powers* instead of *cubes*?

Comment: @lhf: Of course.  Thank you for the correction.  If you feel my answer is too close to yours, I'm happy to erase it.